# Migrating Dreamhost Google Apps Account back to 1and1 then DNS to SquareSpace

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, dreamhost, 1and1

So a little bit of background.

The domain is controlled by my 1and1 account, which currently points DNS to Dreamhost's name servers.

I setup Google Apps in the Dreamhost panel, creating custom MX records.

I now need to forward the domain to SquareSpace.

Squarespace's instructions for pointing 1and1 domains to them suggests creating an A-Record - http://help.squarespace.com/customer/portal/articles/794484 which then changes the email settings to being controlled by 1and1.

If I change the DNS settings in the 1and1 panel will that overwrite/destroy the existing MX records setup in Dreamhost?

Could I simply copy and paste them from Dreamhost?

Could I use Squarespace's name servers instead of creating an A-Record?

Appreciate any help you can give.

Cheers.

Jolyon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1. If I change the DNS settings in the 1and1 panel will that overwrite/destroy the existing MX records setup in Dreamhost?
A1. I don't use 1 and 1 but presumably setting the DNS entries will make 1 and 1's name servers authoritative for your domain.  In any case they'll need to be authoritative for the new A record to have effect.  It won't overwrite them at Dreamhost, but will revoke their authority.

Q2. Could I simply copy and paste them from Dreamhost?
A2. Yes.

Q3. Could I use Squarespace's name servers instead of creating an A-Record?
A3. Is that a service offered by Squarespace?

I would go with option 2, copy the google records from Dreamhost and use 1 and 1's name servers if you're sticking with them as your registrar.

Comment: I think I'll go with option 2, it also means if it all gets borked I'll have a reference  to set it all back. Thanks :-)